# How to get the event sequence between two specific events?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query event data from firebase. The goal is to get the event sequence that starts with event X and ending with event Y. The events are ordered by date.

Eample data:

| user_id | event_name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X |  |
| 1 | b |  |
| 1 | c |  |
| 1 | Y |  |
| 2 | a |  |
| 2 | Y |  |
| 3 | X |  |
| 3 | a |  |
| 3 | b |  |
| 4 | X |  |
| 4 | b |  |
| 4 | Y |  |

the ideal output:

| user_id | event_name | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X |  |
| 1 | b |  |
| 1 | c |  |
| 1 | Y |  |
| 4 | X |  |
| 4 | b |  |
| 4 | Y |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(group_id) from (
  select *, 
    countif(event_name = 'X') over(partition by user_id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) -
    countif(event_name = 'Y') over(partition by user_id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) group_id,
  from your_table 
)
qualify 2 = countif(event_name in ('X', 'Y')) over(partition by user_id, group_id)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]